# How to implement One-to-Many mapping when the associative table is one for all one-many relationships?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

General case: first table represents *one*-side, second table represents *many*-side. Third table serves as a link between the two.

My case: first and second tables are the same. Third table serves as a link between all pairs of tables which have one-to-many relationship. This third table has additional field (String) which contains information about 2 tables.

Little example. Suppose we have tables Project and Category (one category --> many projects). To obtain all projects with categories we need to perform next query:

```
select project.name, category.name 
from nodeassociation, project, category 
where nodeassociation.association_name='ProjectCategory'
 and nodeassociation.source_id=project.id 
 and nodeassociation.sink_id=category.id
```

How can I specify association_name criterion by means of JPA?

UPD: if it's impossible with JPA but hibernate handles it then it's ok, what's the hibernate solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a suitable solution with native queries.

In a nutshell:

1. I made simple mapping for Project and Category without any relationships (like OneToMany)
2. I add field `category` to Project entity and marked it as `@Transient`
3. In ProjectDAO I manually insert category to project, using native queries.

Article about [JPA Native Queries](http://blog.randompage.org/2006/06/jpa-native-queries.html) and [related jboss docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/query_native.html) were a startpoint for me.

Comment: Then you don't have automatic persistence of the relationship by hibernate:if you add a category to your project, and save the project, you will need to persist the category and the association yourself. You lose a lot of the power of hibernate then. The DAO could do the job if you save object using it, but the you can't simply load/modify entities, you need to load/modify/save each time. Maybe an EntityListener could do the job in a more transparent way.

Comment: I'll read about EntityListener. You're right and I knew all this before your comment appeared but I don't see any other way out. 
I can't modify DB schema.

My application only reads from DB and this allows me to change objects manually. Otherwise I would probably think twice before applying my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you create multiple views in the database filtered on the `association_name` column, and then define many-to-many relationships in your mapping based on these, and just enforce the one-to-many semantics in your code. This situation with an intermediate table is only really handled in Hibernate using a many-to-many mapping.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally called a [qualified association](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/com.soyatec.uml.doc/annotations/annotations/association%20.html). Such association should be realized with `Map` instead of `List`. There is not built in support for these in hibernate. If you don't care about the qualifier, the association become a plain many-to-many that can be handled with hibernate.

But in your case this isn't a qualified association at the logical level. If I understand well, one association table is used to represent what is actually *several* associations:

- If you can change the db schema to have on table per *logical* association, the problem vanishes.
- Using database views to "simulate" having separate tables (as suggested by David M) is an alternative. Create one view per *logical* association and map it as a many-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that work *maybe* would be to have a polymorphic entity for `NodeAssociation` in hibernate. There would be one `NodeAssociationX` entity per type of association. There is then a one-to-many association between `Project` and `NodeAssociation`. And there is a one-to-many per `NodeAssociationX` and the corresponding table/entity (`Category`, etc.). You can map the private fields so that you can provide public getter/setter that provide the correct view at the logical level.

```
public List getCategories()
{
     List categories = new ArrayList();
     for( NodeAssociation na : nodeAssociations )
     {
           if( typeof( na ) = NodeAssociationCategory )
           {
                categories.addAll( ((NodeAssociationCategory)na).getCategories() ); 
           }
     }
     return categories;
}
```

But this is rather ugly. Try the other solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
public class Category {

    private Integer id;

    @Id
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    private LinkBetweenOneCategoryAndManyProject linkClass = new  LinkBetweenOneCategoryAndManyProject();

    @OneToOne
    public LinkBetweenOneCategoryAndManyProject getLinkClass() {
        return this.linkClass;
    }

    public void addProject(Project project) {
        getLinkClass().getProjectList().add(project);
    }

    // delegates to LinkClass
    public String getAdditionalProperty() {
        getLinkClass().getAdditionalProperty();
    }

}
```

Now our Project

```
@Entity
public class Project {

    private Integer id;

    @Id
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

}
```

Now our LinkBetweenOneCategoryAndManyProject class

```
@Entity
public class LinkBetweenOneCategoryAndManyProject {

    private Integer categoryId;

    private String additionalField;

    List<Project> projectList;

    @Id
    public Integer getCategoryId() {
        return this.categoryId;
    }

    @OneToMany
    public List<Project> getProjectList() {
        return projectList;
    }

    public String additionalProperty() {
        return this.additionalField;
    }

}
```

So if you want to retrieve a Category and its project, do as follows

```
select distinct c from Category c left join fetch c.linkedClass lc left join fetch lc.projectList
```

Takes care i suppose the relationship between Category and LinkBetweenOneCategoryAndManyProject is OneToOne

regards,